# Multiple tables in Microsoft Access that need to feed into one table

Tags: microsoft-access

In my Access (2010) database, I have 4 linked tables (from other Access databases) that I would like to feed into one table, or query. I've tried using the query design but can't seem to get it right. Each table has the following columns:

Date, ColorID, PartCategory, PartSubcategory, MilThickness, Painter, Paint Line, Pre/Post Cure, Reading Number, Inspector, Time.

Like I said before I would like to be able to see the data records of all 4 linked tables in one table or query, but I would need instructions on how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

This will return everything from all 4 tables as one recordset:

```
Select * from Table1
Union
Select * from Table2
Union
SElect * from Table3
Union
Select * from Table4
```

You would need to put this in SQL view of your query and replace Table1 etc, with the actual table names.

For more information about using Union, you can go [here.](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/combine-the-results-of-several-select-queries-by-using-a-union-query-HA010206109.aspx)